# Activity <Activity name> has leaked window DecorView@59feb10[activity] that was originally added here

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        new SweetAlertDialog(context,SweetAlertDialog.NORMAL_TYPE)
                .setTitleText("Cancel Create Account?")
                .setContentText("Do yo u really want to cancel sign up? press yes to exit.")
                .setConfirmText("Yes")
                .setCancelText("No")
                .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                        sweetAlertDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                        RegisterMerDetailsActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
```

show method pointed to the leaked window error.I am still trying why this happening. but still, get same error.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code

```
@override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    sweetAlertDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass Activity name instead of context.

like this :

new SweetAlertDialog(YourActivity.this,SweetAlertDialog.NORMAL_TYPE).show();